# Applying IIS rewrite rules from both parent and child directory for Blazor WebAssembly standalone app

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, blazor, web-config, blazor-webassembly

I am trying to configure a directory structure in an IIS website to host multiple versions of a Blazor WebAssembly standalone app, with each version residing separately in its own directory. I want to use rewrite rules in the `web.config` at the root level to determine which version of the app is served, based on a cookie (as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8764378/14207973)). However, Blazor needs to have [its own `web.config`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly#webconfig) in its directory, with rewrite rules to serve its `wwwroot` subdirectory and provide SPA fallback routing. I can't get the two sets of rewrite rules to work together for the same request.

Take the following simplified structure. I have added a `hello.txt` file to the `wwwroot` directory of the Blazor app for testing.

```
Default Web Site
├─ web.config
└─ v1
   ├─ web.config
   └─ wwwroot
      ├─ index.html
      └─ hello.txt
```

[image]

I want to be able to access `hello.txt` through http://localhost/hello.txt. I have configured the `web.config` at the website root level like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite to v1" stopProcessing="false">
          <match url="^(?!v1).*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="v1\{R:0}" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

And I have copied the `web.config` generated by Blazor into the `v1` directory (relevant excerpt below):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Serve subdir">
          <match url=".*" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot\{R:0}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="SPA fallback routing" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="wwwroot\index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The one-level rewrite works when I access http://localhost/v1/hello.txt, but the two-level rewrite doesn't work for http://localhost/hello.txt; see image below. Note that changing the rewrites to redirects allows the file to be served successfully (but causes the URL in the address bar to change, which I don't want).

[image]

Is there a way of getting this to work, or it is some limitation of the URL Rewrite Module? Microsoft seems to claim that multiple configuration levels are supported in the [URL Rewrite Module Configuration Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference#rules-inheritance):

> **Rules Inheritance**
>
> If rules are defined on multiple configuration levels, the URL Rewrite Module evaluates the rules in the following order:
>
> 1. Evaluate all the global rules.
> 2. Evaluate a rule set that includes distributed rules from parent configuration levels as well as rules from the current configuration level. The evaluation is performed in a parent-to-child order, which means that parent rules are evaluated first and the rules defined on a last child level are evaluated last.

I'm aware that I can make the `web.config` at the website root level reference Blazor's `wwwroot` subdirectory directly (through `url="v1\wwwroot\{R:0}"`). However, I don't want to do this. I will eventually be extending the outer `web.config` to support other versions of my app (`v2`, `v3`, …), which may or may not also have a `wwwroot` subdirectory, depending on future versions of Blazor and whether we keep using Blazor. Hence, it would be much cleaner to maintain any version-specific rewrites to inner subdirectories in the Blazor version-specific `web.config`.

I've tried using Failed Request Tracing. The outer rule, `Rewrite to v1`, is logged to run successfully. There is no mention of the inner rule, `Rewrite to wwwroot`.

[image]

Comment: Try using failed request tracing to see details about 404 error.

Comment: @samwu: The error page explains the 404 – it's trying to locate the file under `v1\hello.txt` instead of `v1\wwwroot\hello.txt`.